# Linux Server login screen

Tags: linux, shell, authentication

I wonder what program the login screen of linux/unix server which is black and white is?
Is it a part of shell or another program? 
Is it possible to replace it with self make program?
For examples: 
[image: sample login screen]
<sub>(source: [labtestproject.com](http://www.labtestproject.com/files/screenshot/fedora13/047_fedora13_shell_login.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `/bin/login` started from [`getty`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getty_%28Unix%29) in `/etc/inittab`, which is configuring the behavior of `/sbin/init` which is *magically* started by the kernel at boot time. `init` is nearly the only process not obtained by `fork`-ing.

See also [agetty(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/agetty.8.html). You can replace `/bin/login` by something else.

Notice that `init` is becoming [systemd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/init.1.html) on recent Linux distributions.

Read e.g. the [from powerup to bash prompt howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/From-PowerUp-To-Bash-Prompt-HOWTO.html)